# logstash grok filter-grok parse failure

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have multiline custom logs which I am processing as a single line by the filebeat multiline keyword. Now this includes \n at the end of each line. This however causes grok parse failure in my logstsash config file. Can someone help me on this. Here is how all of them look like:

Please help me with the grok filter for the following line:

> 11/18/2016 3:05:50 AM : \nError thrown is:\nEmpty
>   Queue\n*************************************************************************\nRequest sent
>   is:\nhpi_hho_de,2015423181057,e06106f64e5c40b4b72592196a7a45cd\n*************************************************************************\nResponse received is:\nQSS RMS Holds Hashtable is
>   empty\n*************************************************************************

Comment: If you could post your *logstash config*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mohsen suggested you might have to use the [gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) filter in order to replace all the **new line** characters in your log line.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      # replace all forward slashes with underscore
      "fieldname", "\n", ""         
    ]
  }
}
```

Maybe you could also do the above within an `if` condition, to make sure that there's no any `grokparse` failure.

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] or "_dateparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop { }
}else{
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      # replace all forward slashes with underscore
      "fieldname", "\n", ""         
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses, this worked!!

Comment: can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576560/logstash-grok-parsing-for-xml

Comment: What is the point of dropping here? You still have to handle that error or else you are losing a piece of data by throwing it away.

Answer (score 1):

you can find your answer here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

you should use Mutate block to replace all `"\n"` with `""`(empty string).
or use this

```
%{DATESTAMP} %{WORD:time} %{GREEDYDATA}
```

Comment: can you please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576560/logstash-grok-parsing-for-xml